Advice on how to stick new tile on previously tiled wall
I need to replace these missing tiles to pass a FHA appraisal. The texture intimidates me. What can I use to make the new tile stick to it? Can I use modge podge?


Texture is good for adhesion. Problems occur when surfaces are too smooth, which is definitely not the case here! But... is it stable? When you scratch that surface with a screwdriver blade, does it crumble into dust? Do bits come off? Or is it solid?

while tile adhesive is often white, it is not white glue,

"The texture intimidates me" you'll add thin set to the wall which will fill all the rough uneven low spots and give you an even surface. Then add thin set to the back of the tile with a notched trowel. press the tile onto the wall. Remove the tile and make sure it bonded everywhere, if it didn't add more thinset. If it sits too high remove some thin set.

This looks like a common mortar on lath wall in a 40-50s built home in the southeast.
Just brush off any loose particles and use thin-set mortar to replace the tile. Allow a day to dry then grout with an un-sanded grout.  FHA will be fine with it.
